# How to put test dataframe in the same dataframe of prediction dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset that I have broke into

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state =34)
```

I have built my mode and got the predictions

```
mdl.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_pred = mdl.predict(X_test)
```

Now I want to have a look at the predicted values side by side alone with the `y_test` values

I did this

```
pd.DataFrame(y_pred).join(y_test)
```

but results were `NaN` for most values

```
                 0  AdmAfter12Mths
0      1.113033e+00             NaN
1      1.794673e+00             NaN
2     -1.279929e-01             NaN
3      8.467617e-01             NaN
4      1.315781e+00             NaN
5      5.421329e-01             NaN
6      1.203635e-01             NaN
7      9.216141e+00             NaN
8      1.248840e+01             NaN
9      1.027268e+00             7.0
10     3.767157e-02             NaN
```

I tried another way

```
pd.concat([y_test, pd.DataFrame(y_pred)], axis=1)
```

Same reslts

```
                0  AdmAfter12Mths
0        1.113033             NaN
1        1.794673             NaN
2       -0.127993             NaN
3        0.846762             NaN
4        1.315781             NaN
5        0.542133             NaN
6        0.120363             NaN
7        9.216141             NaN
8       12.488396             NaN
9        1.027268             7.0
10       0.037672             NaN
```

I realized that dataframe index could be the problem

but

How can I put both `y_pred` and `y_test` in the same dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `reset_index()`

```
pd.concat([y_test.reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(y_pred)], axis=1)
```